# windows 7 backup failure insufficiant disk space

Tags: windows, backup

Windows 7 backup fails and gives me the message that there is insufficient disk space. I have over 2oo gigs of free space on one drive and 900 on the other.

Comment: Do you use FAT32 on those disks by any chance ?

Answer (score 1):

System reserved partition didn't have enough free space to create the back up image temp files so I shrank the C: partition by 500mb, created new partition of 500mb and labelled it as active, restart with win 7 DVD and select start up repair ran it twice to create new MBR etc. When this is done and win 7 is starting witout any issues delete system reserved partition. Image backup has worked without a problem ever since.

100mb may be more than enough to create a boot and recovery partiition but it doesn't allow enough space for the image backup temp files to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the destination disk (disk you're backing up TO) from Basic to Dynamic.

1. Click the Windows button
2. Right click on Computer and select Manage
3. Click on Disk Management in the left pane
4. Select and then right click on the Disk you want to convert
5. Select "Convert to Dynamic Disk"
6. Use defaults through wizard

Hope this helps!

Comment: @r0ca: Why would you suggest this? You cannot revert back to Basic disk, AFAIK, and Dynamic has its own set of pitfalls. Why and how would this actually solve OP's problem?

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer then. Because, I'm not talking of reverting to basic. AND, it's a viable solution.